How to delete multiple org trees in a row?
I am trying to delete multiple org trees from the same buffer in a sequence:
(org-map-entries (lambda ()
                   (when conditions...
                    (org-cut-subtree)) nil nil)

I get unexpected results with that code. Mostly, from what I tested, entries that should be deleted are skipped sometimes, and get deleted the next time I run the function.
I think the cause is that I modify the buffer by cutting the subtree, and if org-map-entries uses positions, it might mess up its sequence.
So I tried adding entries positions to list, reverse it, and then deleting entries from the end of the buffer, this way I thought entries positions should remain the same after cutting the previous ones:
(let ((entries-to-delete '()))
  (org-map-entries (lambda ()
                     (if conditions ...
                         (push (point) entries-to-delete)))  nil nil)
  (dolist (pos (nreverse entries-to-delete))
    (goto-char pos)
    (org-cut-subtree)))


I get the same results, but this time, in reverse :)
The last thing I can think of is count how many entries I got to delete, and running my org-map-entries that many times. But I think I must be missing something, and I'd rather ask for help before resorting to such an ugly solution.
Thanks for your help.

Your diagnosis is correct I believe. I was going too suggest the "delete from the end" solution and I still think that should work, but I have not tried it and I have not tried to debug your solution. But read the fourth paragraph in C-h f org-map-entries (the one that starts The call to FUNC will be wrapped into a ‘save-excursion’ form...) which addresses this problem and mentions org-map-continue-from. That might be a better solution to your problem.

"Delete from the end" does work, but your code has a bug: push pushes an element to the front of the list, so since org-map-entries goes from the beginning of the file to the end, the positions in entries-to-delete are already in decreasing order: the nreverse then puts them in increasing order, so you end up with the same problem you had before :-)

Thanks the code works fine now, and you proved that once again, the usual suspects should be considered seriously one by one. First, check-parens, then if the results do not make sense, read the doc again. My workaround made sense, all I had to do was read the push info, where the example snippet shows exactly why it did not work. For the org-map-entries-continue-from variable, good catch. I am glad I did not stick to a workaround because I was certain such a common issue would have a canonical solution to it. Again, it was in the doc :) Thanks again for the help.

Per my comment, this seems to work:
* foo

stuff

** more stuff
more stuff

* something else
something else

* bar
bar

* baz
baz

* Code

#+begin_src elisp
     (org-map-entries (lambda ()
                        (when (member (org-get-heading) '("foo" "bar" "baz"))
                         (org-cut-subtree)
                         (setq org-map-continue-from (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) (point)))))  nil nil)

#+end_src

As C-h f org-map-entries says:
...
The call to FUNC will be wrapped into a ‘save-excursion’ form, so FUNC
does not need to preserve point.  After evaluation, the cursor will be
moved to the end of the line (presumably of the headline of the
processed entry) and search continues from there.  Under some
circumstances, this may not produce the wanted results.  For example,
if you have removed (e.g. archived) the current (sub)tree it could
mean that the next entry will be skipped entirely.  In such cases, you
can specify the position from where search should continue by making
FUNC set the variable ‘org-map-continue-from’ to the desired buffer
position.

...

Alternatively, the delete-from-the-end strategy does work (as indicated in my second comment), but your code has a bug: entries to-delete is already in decreasing order, so the nreverse is not only unnecessary, it is positively harmful. If you get rid of it, then the code works as desired.
